# specify how to partition dask dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask

I have a pandas df that's indexed by `id` and `date`. I would like to run some regressions for each id in parallel using dask. I know dask splits the df into N partitions but is there a way to force it to split by `id` column? This way when I do `map_partitions` I can simply apply my rolling regression function to each partition.